# sql server 2000 on windows 8

Tags: windows-8, sql-server-2000

I had installed `SQL Server 2000` on my `Windows 8`. But the `SQL Server` cannot start. When I try to start the server I get this error:

> The specified service does not exists as an installed service

Have you any idea?

Comment: Run MSSQL 2000 as application? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa214023(v=sql.80).aspx

Comment: I am pretty sure their is a more detailed error log, you should post it, so we can research what happen before the error was displayed.

Answer (score 2):

Have you checked this out?

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/285100/en-us

It looks like the SQL service may fail in instances where the server name (your Windows 8 computer name) contains all lowercase characters, or a mixture of lower and uppercase.

This is also mentioned here:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlsetupandupgrade/thread/01d1192c-a6df-429c-95d9-e75204ea17b8/